# Generate unique combinations

Tags: shell, sorting, sh, combinations, unique

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the list of letters
letters=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m")

# Define the output file
output_file="5_letter_subsets_sorted_unique.txt"

# Generate all 5-letter subsets without repetition
for a in "${letters[@]}"; do
    for b in "${letters[@]}"; do
        for c in "${letters[@]}"; do
            for d in "${letters[@]}"; do
                for e in "${letters[@]}"; do
                    # Ensure no repetition in the subset
                    if [ "$a" != "$b" ] && [ "$a" != "$c" ] && [ "$a" != "$d" ] && [ "$a" != "$e" ] && \
                       [ "$b" != "$c" ] && [ "$b" != "$d" ] && [ "$b" != "$e" ] && \
                       [ "$c" != "$d" ] && [ "$c" != "$e" ] && \
                       [ "$d" != "$e" ]; then
                        subset=$(echo "$a$b$c$d$e" | grep -o . | sort | tr -d '\n' | uniq)
                        echo "$subset" >> "$output_file"
                    fi
                done
            done
        done
    done
done

echo "5-letter subsets (sorted and unique) generated and saved in $output_file"
```

The above program generates all unique combinations of 5 letters from these set of letters  letters=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m") without repetition, where each combination is sorted in alphabetical order.

Issue - There is a repetiton in the current out put

I have used uniq to remove all the duplicates from the output.

Current Output

```
abcde
abcdf
abcdg
abcdh
abcdi
abcdj
abcdk
abcdl
abcdm
abcde
abcef
abceg
abceh
abcei
abcej
abcek
abcel
abcem
abcef
.
.
.
ijklm
```

Expected Output

```
abcde
abcdf
abcdg
abcdh
abcdi
abcdj
abcdk
abcdl
abcdm
abcef
abceg
abceh
abcei
abcej
abcek
abcel
abcem
.
.
.
ijklm
```

Comment: Checking `[ "$a" != "$b" ] && [ "$a" != "$c" ]` is a lot of code. Consider rewriting it using recursion, where at every function call you just pass the alphabet reduced by used letter. `echo "$a$b$c$d$e" | grep -o . | sort | tr -d '\n' | uniq` is pointless, sorting a single one line?

Answer (score 0):

One liner in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr)<sup>*</sup> Lisp, that we can run from the system command line with `-e`:

```bash
$ rm -f 5_letter_subsets_sorted_unique.txt
$ txr -e '(file-put-lines "5_letter_subsets_sorted_unique.txt" 
                          (comb (join "a".."m") 5))'
$ wc 5_letter_subsets_sorted_unique.txt
1287 1287 7722 5_letter_subsets_sorted_unique.txt
$ head 5_letter_subsets_sorted_unique.txt
abcde
abcdf
abcdg
abcdh
abcdi
abcdj
abcdk
abcdl
abcdm
abcef
$ tail 5_letter_subsets_sorted_unique.txt
gijkm
gijlm
giklm
gjklm
hijkl
hijkm
hijlm
hiklm
hjklm
ijklm
```

I believe the problem is asking about non-repeating combinations, of which there are 5 choose 13 or 1287. This is a substantially smaller space than the space of all repeating combinations of the symbols, which is 13^5 = 371293.

Since the input string from which combinations are being taken is sorted, the combinations produced by `comb` are also sorted; the element combinations are taken from the input sequence in the order they appear in that sequence.

---

* TXR 293 is required due to a fix in the `comb` function.

Answer (score 0):

A naïve approach (assumes letters list is sorted):

```
for a in "${letters[@]}"; do
    for b in "${letters[@]}"; do
        [[ $a < $b ]] || continue
        for c in "${letters[@]}"; do
            [[ $b < $c ]] || continue
            for d in "${letters[@]}"; do
                [[ $c < $d ]] || continue
                for e in "${letters[@]}"; do
                    [[ $d < $e ]] || continue
                    echo "$a$b$c$d$e" >> "$output_file"
                done
            done
        done
    done
done
```

Slightly less naïve (also assumes letters are sorted):

```
na=0
for a in "${letters[@]}"; do
    ((nb=++na))
    for b in "${letters[@]:nb}"; do
        ((nc=++nb))
        for c in "${letters[@]:nc}"; do
            ((nd=++nc))
            for d in "${letters[@]:nd}"; do
                ((ne=++nd))
                for e in "${letters[@]:ne}"; do
                    echo "$a$b$c$d$e"
                done
            done
        done
    done
done > "$output_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Example C code using next pemutation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* assumes n >= 2 */
int nextperm(char *A, int n)
{
int i, j, t;
    while(1)                            /* generate next permutation */
    {
        i = n-2;                        /* scan backwards until */
        while(A[i] >= A[i+1])           /* A[i] < A[i+1] */
            i--;
        if (i < 0)                      /* return if done (all reversed) */
            return 0;
        j = n-1;                        /* scan backwards until */
        while (A[j] <= A[i])            /* A[j] > A[i] */
            j--;
        t    = A[i];                    /*  swap indexes */
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = t;
        i++;                            /* reverse elements */
        j = n-1;
        while (i < j)
        {
            t    = A[i];                /*  swap indexes */
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = t;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}

void show(char *A, int n)
{
int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%1c ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

#define SIZE 5
static char A[] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m'};

int main ()
{
    show(A, SIZE);
    while(nextperm(A, SIZE))
        show(A, SIZE);
    return(0);
}
```

If the array elements can't be compared, an array of indexes 0 to n-1 can be permuted and used to index the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void initperm(int *I, int n)            /* init */
{
int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        I[i] = i;
}

int nextperm(int *I, int n)
{
int i, j, t;
    if(n < 2)                           /* return if only one index */
        return 0;
    while(1)                            /* generate next permutation */
    {
        i = n-2;                        /* scan backwards until */
        while(I[i] >= I[i+1])           /* I[i] < I[i+1] */
            i--;
        if (i < 0)                      /* return if done (all reversed) */
            return 0;
        j = n-1;                        /* scan backwards until */
        while (I[j] <= I[i])            /* I[j] > I[i] */
            j--;
        t    = I[i];                    /*  swap indexes */
        I[i] = I[j];
        I[j] = t;
        i++;                            /* reverse elements */
        j = n-1;
        while (i < j)
        {
            t    = I[i];                /*  swap indexes */
            I[i] = I[j];
            I[j] = t;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}

void show(char *A, int *I, int n)
{
int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%1c ", A[I[i]]);
    printf("\n");
}

#define SIZE 5
static int I[SIZE];                     /* indexes */
static char A[] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m'};

int main ()
{
    initperm(I, SIZE);
    show(A, I, SIZE);
    while(nextperm(I, SIZE))
        show(A, I, SIZE);
    return(0);
}
```